# formatter with components and components with modules shows different results

Tags: views, commerce

i want to create a row using views showing an order and separate tax, shipping, total and subtotal.

When I use the formatter 'Formatted Amount With Components' it shows the result in the attached screenshot, like this:
Subtotal: $3.76
Shipping $10.42
Sales Tax $0.99
Order Total $15.17

But when I use [commerce price components](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components) an[image]d check all components (sales tax, base price, discount, fee, shipping, free shipping) it only shows $3.76

If there is another way to display shipping and tax separately I'd appreciate it as well many thanks.